# chrome extension call specific function

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a **popup.js**:

```
function registerButtonAction(tabId, button, action) {
    // clicking button will send a message to
    // content script in the same tab as the popup
    button.addEventListener('click', () => chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { [action]: true }));
}

function setupButtons(tabId) {
    // add click actions to each 3 buttons
    registerButtonAction(tabId, document.getElementById('start-btn'), 'startSearch');
    registerButtonAction(tabId, document.getElementById('deals-btn'), 'startDeals');
}

function injectStartSearchScript() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        // Injects JavaScript code into a page
        // chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { file: 'main.js' });

        // dd click handlers for buttons
        setupButtons(tabs[0].id);
    });
}

injectStartSearchScript()

// document.getElementById('inject-btn').addEventListener('click', injectStartSearchScript);
```

Which I use to inject my script into the page with the "start-btn" inside my popup.html.

This is my **main.js** which includes my functions I would like to call on a page:

```
function pong() {
    // do something
}

function ping() {
// do something else
}
```

my **manifest.json**:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "test app",
    "description": "test desc",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["main.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

So basically my setup is that I have a popup.html which includes 3 buttons and they should call one of the functions inside my main.js dpending on what button i press.

But I can not get that working. Currently I only can make at least one function call if I directly call pong() inside main.js on load. But I would need to call one of the functions after I click on a button inside my popup.html.

**EDIT:** I have updated the code as far as I understood. I am very sorry but I don't understand what would be needed to be changed else to fulfill your proposal. I mean how to write it to be more correct.

**EDIT 2:** I have removed the line `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { file: 'main.js' });` as well as `document.getElementById('inject-btn').addEventListener('click', injectStartSearchScript)`and added `injectStartSearchScript()`into the popup.js file. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated and complete example with explanation (you are almost there!)

**manifest**

You manifest looks good, no changes needed there.

This configuration says to load the content script in each tab. So before popup even opens each tab will have "main.js" injected into it (exactly once).

**popup.js**

Popup script looks good, no changes needed there.

The tab lookup is still necessary, since to send a message to a specific tab, must know its id. The popup looks for the currently active tab in current window (same as the popup is in) and sets up the button click actions to send a message to the tab.

**main.js**

Will need minor changes here

- Make sure to register the [onMessage listener](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessage), as included in the example below.
- note the conditions: `message.startSearch` and `message.startDeals` -- these must match the messages sent from the popup, i.e. when popup sends a message with content `{startDeals: true}`, the if condition is `startDeals`. It is matching by a key in the sent message and if the key does not match any condition, the message is going to be ignored.

```js
function pong() {
    // do something
    alert('Start!');
}

function ping() {
    // do something else
    alert('Deals!');
}

// register listener to receive messages
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message => {

    // what to do on each received message:
    if (message.startSearch) pong();
    else if (message.startDeals) ping();
});

// sanity check: content has loaded in the tab
console.log('content loaded');
```

One more note as it relates to debugging extensions (and perhaps a source of some of these debugging issues) when the content script has been configured to be injected in the manifest, Chrome will inject main.js into tabs, in a separate extension context. If, after this injection, the developer reloads the extension (circular arrow in `chrome://extensions` or other tool), this will invalidate the context of the content script in the tab. The tab has to be reloaded to reactivate the content script. This is not an issue with a real user, but it does happen during debugging, so double check this is not the cause of issues while debugging.

Comment: I tried to understand this but I struggeled with the documentation from google. Your explanation is totally easy and cear!

Comment: There is one more issue now. Everytime I want to click the button to perform e.g. Pong() it is adding on top. so it wants to start 2, times, 3 times and so on.

Comment: And I have to inject the script per button every time I want to perform pong(). It seems the injection is the issue. I think since I must inject it every time before I can use another button it adds

Comment: u have an idea why it adds up the messages  @Neea ?

Comment: it seems it builds new event listeners everytime I open the popup. thats why all buttons are triggered several times if i keep using the extension on a page

Comment: how would i remove the listener after it has received one "click" message?

Comment: OK I think I understood, I will edit the answer.

Comment: I have updated my first post to do what u adviced. I have problem to understand what exactly needs to be written to make it work from here. I updated manifest.json but when I delete the line `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: 'main.js'});` nothing works anymore. I am not sure how to correctly edit my code to do what u mean. really sorry, I am familiar with python but this chrome extension is blocking me totally right now. @Neea

Comment: I can not tell you how much u helped me with ur last edit as well. I would give 100 upvotes if I could. Much love from a newbie hobby coder <3